# How to check if a path is absolute or relative?

Tags: apache, ant, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm working with Apache Ant and need to check if a property holds an absolute path or relative. How can this be accomplished on Windows?

On a Unix based system, I can easily check for the the '/' int he beginning. Is there a built-in task to check this or a more generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ant 1.8.0 was released there is a feature of the [`property` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) that allows you to convert between relative and absolute paths in a portable way.  In theory then, if you set a property as an absolute path from a path that is already absolute, the two should match, whereas if the first property is *relative,* they should differ.

Here's an illustration:

```
<property name="abs.path" value="C:\my\path" />
<property name="rel.path" value="my\path" />

<property name="abs.candidate" location="${abs.path}" relative="no" />
<property name="rel.candidate" location="${rel.path}" relative="no" />

<echo message="ABS=${abs.candidate}"/>
<echo message="REL=${rel.candidate}"/>
```

Result:

```
Buildfile: build.xml
     [echo] ABS=C:\my\path
     [echo] REL=C:\Martin\my\path
```

The `relative="no"` attribute isn't strictly needed as the default is 'no'.  Note the use of `location=` rather than `value=`, so that Ant knows the path conversion should be applied.